# Xamarin Forms app generates concurrently running apps upon resuming

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, lifecycle

I am developing a cross-platform mobile application using Xamarin Forms. Due to the nature of the app some data needs to be persisted when the user exits out of the app. I am achieving this by using the built-in `Properties` dictionary. [View documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary)

This ties into my question. When I exit out of the app (not terminating it but just putting it to sleep) I can see that the `OnSleep()` method in the `App` class gets invoked. However, upon resuming the app, the app does *not* invoke the `OnResume()` method but the app generates a completely new instance. I.e. it invokes the `OnStart()` method, which will (I assume) create and instantiate a new instance of the application and run this new instance concurrently with the other instance.

This messes with my goal of recreating the state of the app, ultimately resulting in the persisted data either not being loaded at all or intermingling with the new instance to create unexpected behavior.

I will note that I have limited experience developing mobile applications and thus my knowledge of how to (properly) handle the life cycle events are a little vague. However, below I have listed the implementation details.

**Implementation and life cycle details**

I launch the app from the `App` class, which (partially) looks like below:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Manager.GeneratePages();

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                {
                    InitializeAndroidApp();
                    break;
                }
         ...
    }
```

The method body of `InitializeAndroidApp()`:

```
private void InitializeAndroidApp()
{
    bottomBarPage = BottomNavigationBar.generateBottomBarPage();
    AddPagesToBottomBar(DEVICE_ANDROID);
    var NavBar = new NavigationPage(bottomBarPage)
    {
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.White
    };
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(bottomBarPage, false);
    MainPage = NavBar;
}
```

My current (and limited) life cycle handlers (member's of the `App` class):

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[METHOD INVOCATION]: OnStart()");
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[METHOD INVOCATION]: OnSleep()");
    HomePageViewModel.firstSession = false;
    DeviceDetailsViewModel.newSession = false;
    Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("[METHOD INVOCATION]: OnResume()");
}
```

The `OnResume()` method is currently empty, this I am aware of. But, like I mentioned above, I expected the application to automagically "just" resume the current instance and not create a new instance.

What am I missing? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you putting your app in Sleep mode using Back button or Home Button?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar I should have clarified on that. When I put the app in sleep mode using the Back button I get the odd behavior. I can see the `OnSleep()` method being called, and when resuming the app `OnResume()` does __not__ get called but `OnStart()` does - it creates a new instance which will run concurrently with the other instance. When I press the Home button the current instance is put to sleep (I can see `OnSleep()` being called). Upon resuming the app I can see `OnResume()` being called - i.e. __no__ new instance gets created.

Comment: Yes. This is the android app behavior. When you put your app in sleep mode using back button, It will destroy all instance. If you don't want to destroy then use static instance.

Comment: Ok. I will look into static instances. Thanks for the comment!